# Skip Facebook login window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I think to give a chance to user to keep his Facebook login in the database and
somehow to skip Facebook login window.

So technically the idea is to login within a WebBrowser control which has Facebook login page opned.

Is it possible to do:

1. Populate input boxes of this page
2. Click login button
3. And have WebBrowser control hided

Any clue?

Thank you!

Comment: Facebook specifically does not support "silent" login through their API because they know 99% of developers are not qualified to store such sensitive passwords - no matter what device you're on, they force you to use Facebook's login screen for authentication. I would never use a program that stored my Facebook password in its own database. So the short answer is, no, you cannot "skip" the Facebook login window - it would be far too insecure for you to store people's credentials locally.

Comment: @SpikeX OK pls put it like an answer and share some Facebook link that says it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't skip it - Facebook only permits authorization through its own servers and browser windows.

Also, not to sound rude, but you are probably not qualified to store people's Facebook credentials.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ - Note that there is no silent login option where you send the user's password to Facebook - in all authorization examples, there is an official Facebook login window at play.

Comment: Originally there was a protocol known as XAuth which supported silent auth (I think Twitter still uses this) but in most places its being deprecated in favor of OAuth.